# Data from two table with Sum unction

Tags: sql

i use the following query:

```
select name, sum(eq_bal) as eq_bal 
from acc 
where led_id in (19,22,25,26) 
group by name 
order by eq_bal asc
```

the result of query is :

| name | eq_bal |
| --- | --- |
| 88888 | 50,000,000.00 |
| 77777 | 92,000,000.00 |
| 99999 | 99,000,000.00 |
| 22222 | 33,000,000.00 |

i need to add column from another table as below

```
select * from address
```

| name | line |
| --- | --- |
| 88888 | line 1 |
| 77777 | line 2 |
| 99999 | line 3 |
| 22222 | line 4 |

so i need the result as below : -

| name | eq_bal | line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 88888 | 50,000,000.00 | line 1 |
| 77777 | 92,000,000.00 | line 2 |
| 99999 | 99,000,000.00 | line 3 |
| 22222 | 33,000,000.00 | line 4 |

and I need the query as general.

i need to collect data from two different table with using SUM function.

Comment: Strange, the result doesn't come in the ORDER BY order.

Comment: So you want to add the line to the result?

Comment: can you share the table's schema like the col names in the question?

Comment: Why did you revert the formatting improvements? It's so hard to read it as it is now...

Comment: Please provide RDBMS version

Comment: Hi - you just need to join the two tables. This is basic SQL so if you don't know how to join tables then you're probably better off taking one of the many online SQL courses to get you up to speed